# OpenCV not adding line and dots on image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am working with the SparseOptFlow algorithm. I want to track some corners and show them on the image in real time.

This worked very well with .avi videos, now I am working with tiff sequence. 
What's happening is that it doesn't want to show the tracked GREEN corner on the image even if it has the corner and the code is correct.

Here's the code:

```
color = (0, 255, 0)                                                                 # Corner colors (green)
[.....]
while(totAnalyzedFrame[nucleo]<totFrame):
            # ret = a boolean return value from getting the frame, frame = the current frame being projected in the video
            try:
                frame = VideoToSOF[totAnalyzedFrame[nucleo]]
            except Exception as e:
                print("Frame finished...Exception:")
                print(e)

            # Converts each frame to grayscale - we previously only converted the first frame to grayscale (cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), tiff already in grayscale)
            gray = frame
            # Calculates sparse optical flow by Lucas-Kanade method
            # https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk
            next, status, error = cv.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prev_gray, gray, prev, None, **lk_params)

            #Save the information of the corners
            for i in range(len(next)):
                cornerPosition[nucleo][totAnalyzedFrame[nucleo]][i][0] = next[i][0][0]    # X pos of i_th corner 
                cornerPosition[nucleo][totAnalyzedFrame[nucleo]][i][1] = next[i][0][1]    # Y pos of i_th corner
                if next[i][0][0] <= 0 or next[i][0][1] <= 0:
                    printf("Got a '0': frame = %d, X = %d, Y = %d " % (i,next[i][0][0],next[i][0][1]))

            # Selects good feature points for previous position
            good_old = prev[status == 1]
            # Selects good feature points for next position
            good_new = next[status == 1]
            # Draws the optical flow tracks
            for i, (new, old) in enumerate(zip(good_new, good_old)):
                # Returns a contiguous flattened array as (x, y) coordinates for new point
                a, b = new.ravel()
                # Returns a contiguous flattened array as (x, y) coordinates for old point
                c, d = old.ravel()
                # Draws line between new and old position with green color and 1 thickness
                mask = cv.line(mask, (a, b), (c, d), color, 1)
                # Draws filled circle (thickness of -1) at new position with green color and radius of 2
                frame = cv.circle(frame, (a, b), 2, color, -1)
            # Overlays the optical flow tracks on the original frame
            output = cv.add(frame, mask)
            # Updates previous frame
            prev_gray = gray.copy()
            # Updates previous good feature points
            prev = good_new.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
            # Opens a new window and displays the output frame
            cv.imshow("sparse optical flow", output)
            # Frames are read by intervals of 10 milliseconds. The programs breaks out of the while loop when the user presses the 'q' key
            if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                np.delete(prev, [])
                break

            totAnalyzedFrame[nucleo] = totAnalyzedFrame[nucleo] + 1
            print("SOF working... Frame =  %d/%d\t\t\t[press 'q' to quit]" % (totAnalyzedFrame[nucleo],totFrame), end='\r')
    else:
        print("No corner found @ nucleo %d" % nucleo+1)
        pass
```

As you can see I read the corners and try to add it (line and circles) to the image, then show the image. The corner exist and the image is shown but not a single GREEN corner is visualized. They are all black...

Here's the result: Image is shown, tracking working, no green corner and tracked line visualized even if they exist.

[image: not a corner]

Any suggestions?

P.S.: I'm sure the code works because I've tested it with .avi, once I put .tiff it started with the problems. Tiff is gray scale only so maybe it cannot show green dots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you can't plot green color on a Grayscale plane.

The solution is converting image from Grayscale to **BGR** format, and plotting on the BGR image.

Example:
Plotting on Grayscale results a black circle:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

color = (0, 255, 0)

# Read image as Grayscale
gray = cv.imread('chelsea.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

rows, cols = gray.shape

gray = cv.circle(gray, (cols//2, rows//2), rows//4, color, thickness=8)

cv.imshow('gray', gray)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image]

Solution:
Convert form Grayscale to BGR (where r=g=b for each pixel), and plotting on the BGR image:

```
gray = cv.imread('chelsea.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)    
rows, cols = gray.shape

# Convert from Grayscale format to BGR format, where r=g=b for each pixel
bgr = np.dstack((gray, gray, gray))

# Plot the circle on the BGR image:  
bgr = cv.circle(bgr, (cols//2, rows//2), rows//4, color, thickness=8)

cv.imshow('bgr', bgr)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Alternative methods to convert from a grayscale (1-channel) to BGR (3-channel) are: `image = cv2.cvtColor(grayscale_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)` and `image = cv2.merge([grayscale_image, grayscale_image, grayscale_image])`

Comment: @nathancy, I know there are many methods, I am used to MATLAB where the most used syntax is `RGB = cat(3, I, I, I)`. The syntax `np.dstack((gray, gray, gray))` looks like an elegant solution to my view.

Comment: perfect comment. Thanks!